# Why get an InputMismatchException in this elementary Java program?

Tags: java, exception, input, type-mismatch

```
String[] names=new String[4];
int[] scores=new int[4];
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter 4 strings and integers:");
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
  names[i]=keyboard.nextLine();
  scores[i]= keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

Above is my simple program and the following shows the exception that pops up.

```
Enter 4 strings and integers:
first
1
second
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at Q2.main(Q2.java:15)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`nextInt` doesn't swallow the end of line, that stays in the buffer. So when you hit <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>, `1` is read into the first `score`, then the second `name` is set to an empty string.

Then the parser tries to interpret `second` as an `int`, raising the exception.

You'll need to discard the current line after the `readInt`.

Comment: Can you suggest any convenient way to discard the current line after the `readInt`?

Comment: Hint: you are, in fact, already doing it when you read the second `name` :)

Comment: (Second hint: make sure you comment that "discard the rest of the line" thing, otherwise it might look suspicious/strange and confuse people reading the code.)

Comment: Thanks again. It might otherwise confuse me as well after a while :)