# input mismatch exception error student grade and name

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a progam that prompts the user to enter the number of students followed by prompting for username and grade. It runs once (meaning I get asked the number of students, I can enter the first name and number), and then it gives an `InputMismatchException`.

Can you see what's wrong?

```
public class LowestScore {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print ("Enter the number of students");
        int numberOfStudents = input.nextInt();

        int number = 0;

        while (number <= numberOfStudents) {
            number++;
            System.out.println ("Enter student name");
            String studentName = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println ("Enter grade");
            int grade = input.nextInt();
        }
```

Error

```
run: Enter the number of students12 Enter student name Enter grade josje 8    
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at  
java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864) at
java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485) at 
java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117) at 
java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076) at 
demo.LowestScore.main(LowestScore.java:31) Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Please provide the actual exception message and stack trace.

Comment: how about editing the question for better readability

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the carriage return after each of the `nextInt` call.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print ("Enter the number of students");
int numberOfStudents = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine(); // catch it

int number = 0;

while (number <= numberOfStudents) {
    number++;
    System.out.println ("Enter student name");
    String studentName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println ("Enter grade");
    int grade = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine(); // catch it
}
```

Notice that you can still run into an exception if you enter an invalid Integer.

Edit:

Basicly the `nextInt` catches a number that you do input, but it doesn´t catch the carriage return (the new line you are creating by pressing enter). So what it does is, you enter a number for the amount of students, lets say 1. The `nextLine` call instantly gets the carriage Return, creates an empty Student name and you jump straight forward to the next `nextInt` call. This goes on until you reach the complet amount of students. Calling `nextLine` after the `nextInt` catches the carriage return, and you are able to input the student Name.

You can specifically notice this at the point where it does print

```
Enter student name 
Enter grade
```

at the same time. You allways jump directly to the next input for an Integer.

Edit2:

if you would like to catch the Exception for a wrong input aswell, then you could do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberOfStudents = -1;
    boolean exception = true;
    do {
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter the number of students");
            numberOfStudents = input.nextInt();
            exception = false;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {}
        input.nextLine();
    } while (exception);
    int number = 0;
    while (number <= numberOfStudents) {
        exception = true;
        number++;
        System.out.println("Enter student name");
        String studentName = input.nextLine();
        int grade;
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter grade");
                grade = input.nextInt();
                exception = false;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {}
            input.nextLine();
        } while (exception);
        // input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by catch it? Sorry im just starting to learn, so very new to all this.

Comment: Add try{ // your code block }catch(Exception err){err.printStackTrace();}

Comment: @JosjeGerrits check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440819/why-get-an-inputmismatchexception-in-this-elementary-java-program). I did also edit the question to answer it with your example.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of students");
        int numberOfStudents = input.nextInt();

        int number = 0;
        while (number < numberOfStudents) {
            String num = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter student name");
            String studentName = input.next();

            System.out.println("Enter grade");
            int grade = Integer.parseInt(input.next());

            number++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That´s the least thing you would like to do, creating a new Scanner each time.